# Errors while creating outbound conference call in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I am a bit stuck trying to get an outbound call from a Twilio conference.

So far I've tried 2 different ways: using PHP and doing a POST call to the API using curl.

When I use curl, I do the following:

```
curl "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/<my_account_sid/Conferences/<conference_sid>/Participants" -X POST --data-urlencode 'To=<destination_number>' --data-urlencode 'From=<source_number>' --data-urlencode 'EarlyMedia=true' -u [my_account_sid]:[token]
```

And here's the reply I get from the API:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<TwilioResponse><RestException><Code>20006</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><MoreInfo>https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20006</MoreInfo><Status>403</Status></RestException></TwilioResponse>
```

I am always using the main account's credentials and I can use them to do other GETs with curl, so I know that the system is actually authenticating me.

When I use PHP (latest libraries), I try running this script:

```
<?php
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    use Twilio\Rest\Client;
    $ACCOUNT_SID = '<my_account_sid>';
    $AUTH_TOKEN = '<token>';

    $client = new Client($ACCOUNT_SID, $AUTH_TOKEN);
    $participant = $client
        ->conferences("<friendly_name>")
        ->participants
        ->create([
           'from' => '<source_number>',
           'to' => '<destination_number>'
        ]);
?>
```

And the output I get from this script is:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account   \Conference\ParticipantList::create(), called in /var/www/html/voice/conference.php on line 15 and defined in /var/www/html/voice/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/Conference/ParticipantList.php on line 48
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: to in /var/www/html/voice/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/Conference/ParticipantList.php on line 53
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Twilio\Exceptions\RestException' with message '[HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Failed to validate conference attributes' in /var/www/html/voice/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php:85`
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/voice/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php(207): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to creat...')
#1 /var/www/html/voice/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/Conference/ParticipantList.php(87): Twilio\Version->create('POST', '/Accounts/AC893...', Array, Array)
#2 /var/www/html/voice/conference.php(15): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\Conference\ParticipantList->create(Array)
#3 {main}
thrown in /var/www/html/voice/vendor/twilio/sdk/Twilio/Version.php on line 85
```

Please could anyone help me with this?

Thank you very much,

Fabrizio

Comment: Do you have the agent conference setting turned on in [your console](https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/conferences)?

Comment: Oops that was it. Well spotted! That's what the problem was. After enabling agent conference it started working well.

Comment: Fantastic, glad it's sorted!

Comment: @philnash I am still getting same issue, I was trying to add another user in the conference created for agent and customer by task router. i have already enabled Agent Conference on the twilio console. I am using following code: 
 $participants = $this->client
            ->conferences($conferenceId)
            ->participants
            ->create([
                'from' => $this->outboundPhoneDefault,
                'to' => $supervisorPhone
            ]);   But its giving me same error, Can anyone help me here.

Comment: Which version of the Twilio PHP library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, the problem was that I didn't enable Agent Conference on my portal.
See https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/conferences.